# UTF-8 as default in Unity3D new script?

Tags: utf-8, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

I'm from Brazil, and here we use special characters, like "é á í ..." and so on.
I'm using Unity3D and MonoDevelop to program.

But is annoying, every time I use one of this special characters, I have to Open the script in NOTEPAD and re-save it as UTF-8. Just re-saving it in Monodevelop do not work.

Is there a way to fix it, so every new script will be a default UTF-8 ??

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This *might* work:

The files that Unity uses when it creates new script files are found in Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Resources\ScriptTemplates

If you open and re-save them as UTF-8 then hopefully all future scripts created in Unity would keep the formatting.