# Unity js script not working

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have recently taken an interest into unity, and as I guide a chose a playlist from youtube. I have installed the

```
Unity 5.6.4

16 Oct, 2017
```

version as well.

Now, I encounter an error when I try to add a script to an object.

In the tutorial: 
[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceIZqcp7N6A&list=PLZ1b66Z1KFKik2g8D4wrmYj4yein4rCk8&index=6)
, this happens from 11:40 to 13:40.

Basically, as a summary, he is writing a script in js and then attaches it to an object. Now, I have followed the exact steps as him, but it does not work for me.

I write the same script as him, in JS:

[image: jsScript]

then add the script to the object. But then, on the object, I should get a target option, like he does:

[image]

However, I don't get this option on my object:

[image]

The error I get in the console is this:

> Assets/Scripts/PickUp.js(1,386): BCE0044: unexpected char: 0xFEFF.

And this is the actual script:

```
var target : Transform; 
function Update () { } 

function OnMouseDown () 
{ 
    this.transform.position = target.position; 
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FPSController").transform; 
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("FirstPersonCharacter").transform; 
} 

function OnMouseUp () 
{ 
    this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("FPSController").transform; 
    this.transform.parent = null;
}﻿
```

Now, I've heard that it is not the most efficient, but at this point, I don't really care about that, I just want it to work.

Comment: maybe a codepage problem? JS in UTF8 and Unity wants smth else or vice versa? - just guessing

Comment: 0xFEFF is probably a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark . Can you open an editor that shows these kinds of characters (such as Notepad++ with the correct settings). Are there any 'funny' characters, specifically at the end of the file?

Comment: you should use c# ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to save your script using UTF8 - no BOM (ByteOrderMark). If that does not help, save as Ansi and try that - or read up what unity wants :)

[image]

Unity3d Issue Tracker: [textassets-encoding-prefab-with-utf8-bom-encryption-is-corrupted](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/textassets-encoding-prefab-with-utf8-bom-encryption-is-corrupted) it might be related.

This [UTF-8 as default in Unity3D new script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428068/utf-8-as-default-in-unity3d-new-script) was not solved unfortunately.